# Changing Card height in Reactstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am working with Reactstrap and in order to make a certain Card responsive to the size of the window, I want to fix its aspect ratio with percentages, not pixels.

For some reason, this works for width but NOT for height. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xpwOGL

The first line is the problem. If I set height to a constant, say `height:"200px"`, it will make it `200px` just fine. And if I change the width %, it will change the width to match. But for some reason height % just doesn't do anything.

```
<Card style={{width:"80%", height:"60%"}}> 
   <Row className="no-gutters" style={{position: "absolute"}}>
      <Col xs="auto">
        <button>
          Next image
        </button>
      </Col>
      <Col xs="auto">
        <button>
          Previous image
        </button>
      </Col>
    </Row>
 </Card>
```

Is there a different way that I'm supposed to use to make this responsive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The % dimensions are always in *relation to the parent container* of the current element. In this case, your current element is Card and its parent is the div with id app but it has no height fixed. You *need to have some absolute value of the parent container*, then you can make its child element have its % dimension. If you fix the `<div id="app">` height to a certain value, the Card will follow.

And as for your query why it works for width but not for height?

The height of a block element depends on its content unless you specify a specific height. So there is feedback between the parent and child where height is concerned and saying height: 50% doesn't yield a well defined value unless you break the feedback loop by giving the parent element a specific height.

And as far as width is concerned, the `body` of the HTML has a default width of **100%** and its the super-parent element but it also has no height defined unless you specify it or you add elements which expand its height.

Answer (score -1):

dont waste your time in setting up the pixils/percentages for margin and padding and width or height, it's better to use Reactstrap or Semantic UI and pick what's best for you from there.